# Titanium context issue on Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

Am running an app that is working fine in my iOS simulator, but it crashes con my Android emulator, cuz it says that I have not defined a variant.

Here is my example code:

```
/*app.js*/
var myApp = {};
myApp.ui = require("ui");
myApp.ui.createAppTabGroup.open();

/*ui.js*/
function createAppTabGroup() {
    var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();
    myApp.fugitivesTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: L('fugitives'),
        window: fugitives
    });
};
```

I'm declaring "var myApp" before I make the require("ui"), so it should works without problems, and in fact, it works on iOS simulator, but in Android says "myApp is not defined in line `xx myApp.fugitivesTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({"`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem (or advantage) with `require()` is, it loses its context.

For this to work, you will have to re-define myApp again within ui.js, or pass it in the function

The best you can do, is use require only, when it doesn't need anything from the outside, otherwise you will have to give anything to the function itself like this:

```
myApp.ui.createAppTabGroup.open(myApp);

function createAppTabGroup(myApp) {
```

But this is probably not what you would want.

Try doing this instead:

```
/* ui.js */
myApp.ui.createAppTabGroup = function() {


/*app.js*/ 
Ti.include('ui.js');
/* CODE HERE */
myApp.ui.createAppTabGroup.open
```

Comment: Thx for answer. I know that if I use Ti.include() I will solve my problem. But, Titanium peeps says that we should use CommonJs convention, so am using require().  Another thing is that in my iOS simulator it works well. Am getting this error on Android, do you know why on Android an no on iOS?

Comment: oh in that case, I might be wrong. try cleaning your android build (remove the build manually) and retry ;)

Comment: Done. No success :( Can´t understand why it works on iOS but doesn't on Android...